# Accessing a content of an IBOutlet from another class

Tags: swift2, iboutlet

My question is simple , I have an IBoutlet(of a label) declared in a class , I need to change it content from another class , is that possible ?
edit : The view of the IBoutlet is loaded in the other class through a scroll view

the first class :

```
var historyVariable = ""
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
 override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()

 // here a code to set a value to historyVariable when button pressed

 Text().call()

   }
}
```

the second class

```
class  Text: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var History: UILabel!
override   func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
   }
func call() {

History.text = "\(historyVariable)"
 }
}
```

it gives me an error  unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when trying to set the text to the History label

Comment: Your question doesn't explain very well what you're trying to accomplish. Try posting code from the two classes, showing where you want to interact with one another.

Comment: Isn't the compiler complaining about that code, Theilya? — 1) your `@IBOutlet var` should be lower case `history`. — 2) your `func call()` declaration needs to be within the last closing brace of the class declaration. — 3) use upper case `Text` for your class name. Fix those errors first, and update your code above, and whether you're getting other compiler errors or an actual runtime error.

Comment: I've fixed those errors but still , I have the error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when trying to modify the content of the text label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `text()` is actually `Text()`, that would create a new, empty `Text` object.  Since it's not part of the controller hierarchy, its view and other outlets aren't loaded at the time you invoke `call()`.

You either need to instantiate the `Text` controller from a storyboard (or otherwise) and present it so that it's properly initialized or else use one that's already active...if that's your intent.

Comment: it's loaded through a scroll view in the actual first class

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that `Text()` creates a **new** object, not a reference to the one you previously may have loaded.

Comment: the scroll view load a xib where there is History label , I need to reload that History label every time that button is pressed and show the results , how would I do that ?

Comment: When you create a `Text` object from your xib, save a reference to it (probably in `FirstViewController`) and use that reference instead of a new `Text`.

Comment: how would I save a reference to Text ( sorry for those questions but I'am just a beginner )

Comment: In a variable.  If you show how you're doing the xib loading, it would be easier to  give a specific answer.

Comment: the xib code is the one shown at the second class in the question

Comment: You said "the scroll view load a xib".  How does that happen?

Comment: I've created a xib file named History , managed by the History class , in the actual view where there is the scroll view , I've added a scroll view IBOutlet and I've written this code to load the xib file through the scroll view : 

       `let v1 = text(nibName: "History", bundle: nil)     
       @IBOutlet var scroll: UIScrollView!    
       self.addChildViewController(v1)     
        self.scroll.addSubview(v1.view)     
        v1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)     
        self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scroll.frame.width,     self.view.frame.height*10)`

Comment: Then you should be using `v1.call()` if you want to change the Text you already have.